# Symfony 2.6 mapping errors OneToMany inverse side field

Tags: doctrine-orm, mapping, symfony-2.6

I'm searching why I get an error with my mapping but, I really don't see. I red some issues in stack but it doesn't work for me.

**The error :**
*The association CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Address#addressType refers to the inverse side field CTC\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\AddressType#addresses which does not exist.*

Secondly, I also wonder me why when I use my "doctrine:generate:entities ...", that doesn't give me the getter and setter for addresses but well for addressType.

Here is my mapping code :

**class AddressType**

```
...

/*
     * @var array
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="addressType")
     *
     */
    private $addresses;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
...
```

**Class Address**

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\AddressType", inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="addressTypeID", referencedColumnName="AddressTypeID")
     */
    private $addressType;
```

Any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It was just a problem of * !

In the AddressType class, I change this

```
/*
* @var array
* 
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="addressType")
*
*/
private $addresses;
```

**by this**

I just add ONE "*" after "/*" and everything works !

```
/**
* @var array
* 
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="addressType")
*
*/
private $addresses;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
         * @var array
         * 
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="addressType", cascade={"persist","remove"})
         *
         */
        private $addresses;


        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
        }


/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\AddressType", inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="addressTypeID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $addressType;
```

I think your property name for Id inside  addressType entity is not AddressTypeID , I cann't write commit to ask this :( I hope this work phone you